# Flutter release aab bundle error :- Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'

Tags: flutter, dart, build.gradle, release, android-app-bundle

Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             20.2s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1

**Build.gradle File:-**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 32

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "co.demo.flutter"
        minSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
      signingConfigs {
       release {
      keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
          keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
       storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
          storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
//    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:17.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"

}
```